# How can you achieve this mosaic like effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How can i achieve this effect in photoshop? is it hand drawn in illustrator or can it be done using a couple of filters and gradients in photoshop ?

[image]

I found that picture while going through this page.
http://www.digitalartserved.com/gallery/Various-Illustrations-2013/10068071

Comment: That image is **not** the result of running a few filters.

Comment: So , you think its hand drawn in illustrator ? or can it be done using PS alone ? displacement filter maybe ?

Comment: It might be multiple copies of an image trace with varying degrees of detail stacked on each other. But that's in Illustrator and I didn't test that theory.

Comment: Beautiful! I wonder what it would look like with normal coloring. Perhaps it was some kind of live trace mixed with some kind of coloring algorithm? Or maybe it was just a lot of hard, manual work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would think he probably starts with a basic portrait (drawn or live-traced), and then applies the color layers manually.

It's hard to tell, and there's no reason why you can't ask the author himself, but I'm guessing it's **manual work** because of these two pictures in his website's [profile page](http://nosurprises.it/about/):

[image]

[image]

And you can also see the same amount of hand-crafted detail in this other piece from his portfolio:

[image]