# How to create a Geometric Polygonal Art portrait

Tags: shapes, illustration

I've been interested in creating Geometric Polygonal art illustrations, i.e. making polygons and shapes with different color shading represent a face, or an object, see [this](http://pelfind.com/photos/42567/exploring-geometry-30-polygonal-art-illustrations-71607) set of [examples](http://pelfind.com/photos/42567/exploring-geometry-30-polygonal-art-illustrations-71607).

How are they achieved? Is there some script for Illustrator which alters the image adding the shapes according to the colors or shades? How would I transform a normal image of Marilyn Monroe for example, to a polygonal illustration of her?

Comment: We actually had a question about one of the jobs in the first gallery! http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21516/how-can-you-achieve-this-mosaic-like-effect-in-photoshop/21538#21538 These illustrations are probably done manually. There might be a script around, but I doubt you'll ever achieve this level of complexity...

Comment: Here (at tuts+) you will find a great tutorial on how to create a WPAP (Wedha's Pop Art Portrait) portrait in Adobe Illustrator, by the true legend, Wedha Abdul Rasyid: http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-geometric-wpap-vector-portrait-in-adobe-illustrator--vector-16102#comment-1634948249

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, these illustrations were most likely done by hand, as the level of complexity, detail and 'originality' is not something you can achieve with a script.

You could potentially use effects like Mosaic (with triangular shapes), but the results are not nearly as good as your samples. **Your best approach would be to draw each color area yourself.**

However, [**I found this process**](http://jonathanpuckey.com/projects/delaunay-raster/) that actually seems to give some nice results:

[image]

> The Delaunay Raster is an original graphical process I invented in
>   2008, to create abstracted versions of images using the Delaunay
>   Triangulation, color averaging and hand assisted placement of points.
>
> Delaunay Raster was developed using Scriptographer and color averaging
>   by Jurg Lehni.

However, the script is not available in the website, you need to contact the owners if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Some fun from Vitaliy at [another stack exchange site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8513/61):

[image: fun from vitaliy]

Answer (score 1):

You could install something like the [*Processing*](http://processing.org/) IDE and then [search](http://www.openprocessing.org/search/?q=delaunay) and literally load a [*sketch*](http://openprocessing.org/sketch/118949) (replace the assets with yours i.e. jpg files), then grab an image of that:

[image]

This is based on [*Delaunay triangulation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). It is far from perfect but it can help and the source code from such a sketch can be modified. Surely many other frameworks allow for such mathematical *tesselations* but as other answers explain finer work is often done ["by hand"](http://flower2fruit.blogspot.ca/2014/04/how-to-create-polygon-art-in-gimp.html).